# How to display google map based on radius selected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a miles dropdown. When I select any value like 10 miles from dropdown my google map should display within 10-mile range of the place. How Do I do this?

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      function myMap() {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.1304, -106.3468);
            var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 6, scrollwheel: true, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

            marker.setMap(map);
        }
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; "></div>
<div id="searchcontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 450px; top: 0px;">
    <select id="range" name="range">
        <option value="0">Current Map</option>
        <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
        <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
        <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
        <option value="20">20 Miles</option>
        <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
        <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
        <option value="100">100 Miles</option>
        <option value="250">250 Miles</option>
        <option value="500">500 Miles</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure that’s directly possible. Extent relates to zoom levels, which relate lat/long to pixel size. The relationship between latitude and miles varies between the equator and the poles. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates#tile-coordinates and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a [`google.maps.Circle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/#Circle) with the correct center and desired radius, then call `map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds())` (where `circle` is the circle).

(note that radius of the circle is in meters, so you will need to convert your input of miles to meters).

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.34;

function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.1304, -106.3468);
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 6,
    scrollwheel: true,
    draggable: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var circle;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('range'), 'change', function(evt) {
    var value = $("#range").val();
    if (circle && circle.setMap) circle.setMap(null);
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: myCenter,
      radius: value * METERS_PER_MILE,
      map: map
    });
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#googleMap {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<div id="searchcontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 450px; top: 0px;">
  <select id="range" name="range">
    <option value="0">Current Map</option>
    <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
    <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
    <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
    <option value="20">20 Miles</option>
    <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
    <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
    <option value="100">100 Miles</option>
    <option value="250">250 Miles</option>
    <option value="500">500 Miles</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! your code served my purpose. I did not want to display the circle so to your code I just added circle.setMap(null); method.

Comment: Or just don't set the `map` property of the circle to start with (remove the `map: map` line, I "displayed" it on the map to make it obvious what it was doing)

Answer (score 0):

You don't require center in your map. what you can possibly do is to add a listener and upon changing setZoom accordingly but you need to change your range values not text according to Google Maps API documentation to handle max zoom values.

```
var range = document.getElementById("range");
      range.addEventListener("change", function() {
        map.setZoom(range.value);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="range" name="range">
    <option value="0">Current Map</option>
    <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
    <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
    <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
    <option value="20">20 Miles</option>
    <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
    <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
    <option value="100">100 Miles</option>
    <option value="250">250 Miles</option>
    <option value="500">500 Miles</option>
  </select>
I do not want this i just want default 10 miles what should i need to do
```